# Any "virtual filesystem classes" available for storing filesystem folder and file information?

Tags: .net, vb.net, filesystems

Using vb.net, I'm scanning a remote filesystem recursively via UNC for folder and file information (filesizes, etc) and having to do it several times. I'd like to be able to scan the drive once, storing all the folder and file info I need into an object(s) from which I can later get all the info as though it was the original filesystem, perhaps faster. I'd also like to serialize the info for later use if possible.

Is there already a dotnet class of object that I can use to do this?

Comment: You could possibly utilize the [**FileInfo**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) and [**DirectoryInfo**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) classes, but whether they actually store the info or simply gets it at will I don't know (if not you have to design your own classes).

Comment: Sounds like a good application of the simple DBMS like SQLite. Using anything more specialized would likely be an overkill.

Comment: @VisualVincent: I'm aware of FileInfo and DirectoryInfo. Those would be used for obtaining the existing directory/file information. I'm looking for a complete object to contain all the info, a tree structure that can emulate a directory structure's info, including the searching and adding of files.

Comment: Then you'd have to design your own classes. A little hint: In each directory class keep a list of sub-directories and a list of sub-files.